# how to delete all rows using IN OPERATOR in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

i am having problem in understanding the behaviour of this programme below is simple code to delete the email address using IN operator

```
$emails = $_POST['ids'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM newsletter where email ";
    $condition = sprintf('IN ("%s")',implode(' "," ',$_POST['ids']));
    $sql = $sql.$condition;
    include '../includes/db.php';
    $r = mysql_query($sql);

    echo $sql;
```

it only deletes one email id and returns true . how can i make it run in a way it deletes all the emails .

below is the query constructed using the above code.

> DELETE FROM newsletter where email IN ("adfadsf@gmail.com ","
>   asdfasfasf@gmail.com "," kjhkhsd@assdfsdf.sdfsf "," shit@gshit.com ","
>   someother@gmail.com")

is it wrong way of deleteing ?

Comment: I wish my email address was `shit@gshit.com`...

Comment: @todda.speot.is - You can always ask the [domain owners](http://whois.domaintools.com/gshit.com) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$condition = sprintf('IN ("%s")',implode(' "," ',$_POST['ids']));
```

do:

```
$condition = sprintf('IN ("%s")',implode('", "',$_POST['ids']));
```

IN operator matches contents of the field with the values exactly. Spaces at the beginnings and ends of values might have cause your problems.

Answer (score 1):

The query is valid however you are adding spaces before/after the email.

" asdfasfasf@gmail.com " does not match "asdfasfasf@gmail.com"

Answer (score 0):

This code would be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, i could make post something like

```
"); delete from newsletter; delete from newsletter where email in ("
```

the " are part of my post string, this would wipe your newsletter table.

However that aside the key issue with your code is potentially the spaces (do your strings include spaces in the database?) and the use of double quotes.  I'm not 100% certain but I'm sure " can be used as a field indicator rather than a string so you probably want single quotes.

```
$emails = $_POST['ids'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM newsletter where email ";
$condition = sprintf("IN ('%s')",implode("','",$_POST['ids']));
$sql = $sql.$condition;
include '../includes/db.php';
$r = mysql_query($sql);
echo $sql;
```

Output then should be

```
DELETE FROM newsletter where email IN ('adfadsf@gmail.com','asdfasfasf@gmail.com','kjhkhsd@assdfsdf.sdfsf','shit@gshit.com','someother@gmail.com')
```

Comment: Also I've cut and paste the code so it has the same mistake, but you've assigned $emails to $_POST['ids'] but then you reused $_POST['ids'] instead of $emails is that deliberate?

Comment: I wonder why SQL Injection is so hard to understand for newbies. Legacy Mysql extension doesn't support multiple statements but I'm sure you could build a carefully crafted parameter to compose a multi-table delete command and wipe-out any arbitrary data.

Comment: or just do `") or email=email or email in ("`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to insert strings in a SQL query you have to single-quote them and protect against SQL injection. Also, the comma separator in the IN clause should **not** be quoted.

```
$safe_emails = array();
foreach($_POST['ids'] as $i){
    $safe_emails[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($i) . "'";
}
$sql = 'DELETE FROM newsletter WHERE email IN (' . implode(', ', $safe_emails) . ')';
```